# Why was my flag for "offensive/rude" rejected, yet the irrelevent question is "on hold?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

I was reviewing my progress on flag-based badges, and found that a recent flag of mine was decline.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842947/love-friendship-or-forget

I flagged the question for being rude/offensive. Before doing so, I read the FAQ page about [being nice on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). What caught my eye was the following:

> 3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>      ...
>
>    - **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is *not* a dating site.

That bullet point seemed to be most relevant. If you read the question, it is about OP wondering whether he should pursue some girl. Not only does he include (starred out) language, but it is for dating advice.

[Someone even commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842947/love-friendship-or-forget#comment51607502_31842947) noting a similar observation

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming at all. It is dating advice. –  Tyrsius

What really confuses me is how the question is still up, but tagged as being on hold. While i includes a programming tag (javascript), it has nothing to do with programming. It is not salvageable. The only way to make it about programming is to replace the question title and body. I understand it is not "spam" by [SO's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), but it is by the traditional sense.

The question is currently at -9 votes. I am unable to vote to close (for being unsalvageable), and the only one left is "moderator attention." Is there anything I should do about the question, besides ignoring it? Is there a script on SO to automatically close all questions after x downvotes?

Comment: I'm not sure what was offensive to you exactly. Anyway, it is now gone. Those troll questions typically don't last long. Downvote, flag to close/delete if you can, and move on. No need to involve the mods when the community can handle it just fine

Comment: A good example of how *completely* meaningless the term "rude" has become at SO.  It is a 14 year old kid that fell in love with a girl, what on Earth is rude or offensive about that??  Use the appropriate flag, VLQ is the obvious choice.

Comment: @codeMagic I quoted from SO reasons that fall under rude/offensive. I was doing my best to flag appropriately.

Comment: @GEOCHET It was an amusing read to see that question, but I was trying to pick the best flag.

Comment: Why flag? Why not just VTC and then delete?

Comment: @GEOCHET: you cannot vote to close until you have 3k rep. The only option they had was to flag, even if only to flag as off-topic.

Comment: "you cannot vote to close until you have 3k rep" -- Then they shouldn't be worried about the issue. Move on.

Comment: @GEOCHET but you said "why flag". There's nothing wrong with flagging them before 3k. In this case, the OP just needed a better understanding of using the flags

Comment: Well, there is something wrong with flagging if you have to flag something not offensive as offensive just to get noticed. Leave it for the people who can handle it if you don't have the necessary tools.

Comment: @GEOCHET Flagging it as offensive is wrong.  Flagging it for closure as off topic is perfectly fine.  The problem isn't flagging the post, the problem is that he used the wrong flag category.

Comment: Flagging is just a waste of people's time. But clearly, the major WTF here is 'offensive'.

Comment: Can we stop the circling?

Comment: @HunterStevens Don't mind the circling too much on Meta, folks here tend to be opinionated, and also don't mind jesting moreso than elsewhere.  You did good by asking the question to learn better how the site works :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I see the misunderstanding here. It seems to come from

> Also, this is not a dating site.

that is there to mean that we aren't a social network and shouldn't be trying to get dates from members through our posts.

I know we were giving you some grief in the comments but mostly in jest and because it appeared you thought the post was offensive...which it isn't it's just bad and doesn't belong here. It's obviously a troll and not meant to be serious.

> but I was trying to pick the best flag

We appreciate your work. However, these flags go straight to our already too busy mods. Posts like these can be handled just fine and usually quite quickly by the community. As stated in my comment,

> Downvote, flag to close/delete if you can, and move on.

You can flag as off-topic or VLQ but don't use the spam flag, please. I'm sure the mods would appreciate it.

And don't let this keep you from helping try to keep the site clean. It just takes some time and some fails to fully understand the site (someday I hope to).

Comment: What is VLQ? And I appreciate your answer. I expected the lava rain of SO Meta to hit my question. :-)

Comment: @HunterStevens: *Very Low Quality*, a flag type only to be used for posts that need to be deleted *right now* but don't fall under the offensive or spam category. The flag carries an automatic downvote if found to be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

The post *wasn't rude or offensive*. It was wildly off topic, sure. It may even have been posted as a troll (although I see no evidence of that).

You should just have flagged / voted to close the post as off topic. Once the post was brought to my attention, I did just that. If you can only flag, use the [*blatantly off-topic* option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/100297), otherwise fill in a custom reason (I used one that points to the `[help/on-topic]` automatic link).

The *not a dating site* line refers to people trying to hit on other members of the community, not to accidentally mis-filed questions. Note that it is in context of *Inappropriate language or attention*; the OP wasn't directing their attention to other members of the community here, they were trying to figure out what to do about a remark made by a girl they like. That's something very different.

Note that like the *spam* flag, the *rude or offensive* flag carries a hefty -100 point penalty if marked as helpful, and also prime our anti-spam and anti-troll measurements, which you just don't want to inflict on innocent accounts. As such moderators are *very* careful about marking such flags as helpful, quick to decline if it doesn't really apply.

Comment: Thanks I realize that now. Again, I was just trying to do my best. I think I may have been limited a flag type, too. I forget

Comment: _wildly off topic_ posts have [dedicated close flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/165773), don't they?

Comment: @gnat: yes, for people flagging; when you vote to close you are trusted to put in a sensible off-topic reason. Not that that isn't widely misused, of course.

Comment: yeah, 3Kers can give [free-form reason](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zkMIG.png "example"). As asker has 600 rep, their options in are limited to close flags

Comment: I wish I could choose two accepted answers :-) I did not know that point about -100 points. Is that given to the OP, or the person deeming the flag helpful?